# HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed Error for OpenWeatherMap Api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, fetch-api, http-status-code-405

I am trying to fetch api data from Openweathermap and I am getting the following error within my Network tab in my dev tools: 405 Method Not Allowed

Not sure why the error is appearing since it worked when I tried using another API (weather.api.com) using the same code below, the only big difference is that the url in the X-RapidAPI-Host line was different. Could it be the url I have in that line?

```
 const setForecast = () => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "api.openweathermap.org",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "key",
      },
    };

    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${props.searchedCity}&appid={key}`,
      options
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        props.setWeather(data);
        setIsLoaded(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setForecast();
  }, [props.searchedCity]);

  function handleSubmit(e: { preventDefault: () => void }) {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.setSearchedCity(input);
    console.log(input);
  }
```